# Why I need to convert the integer values into string here

Tags: python, typecasting-operator

```
lst1 = [77, "Pizza", 5 , 7, "Burger"]
print(type(lst1[0]), type(lst1[1]))

for i in lst1:
    if i > 6:
        print(i)
```

Since python interpreter can identify that which values of the list are integer and which values of the list are string, why in the if statement it is not working ?

Note: I am not asking the correct code, I just want to know why this code is not working ?

Comment: What do you expect `"pizza" > 6` to be?

Comment: You can not do a < or > between a string and a number.

Comment: Because it's doing what you told it to do? You explicitly told it to go through each item in the list and compare it to an int; why should it do anything else? Just because it might have some "foresight" that the comparison is going to fail doesn't mean it should go ahead and decide for you that it will just skip those elements. That behaviour would become very broken very quickly across your code base

Comment: The core problem is that `>` is not defined for str. What would you expect if `>` is applied to a string?

Comment: @albert of course `>` is defined for string. I would expect lexicographic ordering for the comparison, which is exactly what you get

Comment: @roganjosh: You're definitely correct. I silently implied "when comparing to an integer" which resulted in my ambiguous comment. Sorry.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Since the Python interpreter knows that Pizza is a string, why is it not showing only the integer values larger than 6?

Comment: because that's not how programming works. You don't want the code to make assumptions like: Oh, here the user is comparing a string and a number, let's skip this case. That would be terrible, since you would never know what the program actually does. So the program will do exactly what you tell it to do. In your code you say: for each element of list, check is this element is greater than 6. so the computer compares "pizza" and 6.

Answer (score 2):

Let's ignore the ints in the array for a second and just run:

```
lst1 = ["Pizza", "Burger"]

for i in lst1:
    if i > 6:
        print(i)
```

This will fail because it cannot compare "Pizza" and 6. Adding integers in the array does not change this fact.

It knows they are different, but there is no ordering between strings and intergers, therefore it cannot compare "Pizza" and 6.

Answer (score -3):

You just need to make sure the type is an integer, and then see if it's bigger than 6

```
lst1 = [77, "Pizza", 5 , 7, "Burger"]
print(type(lst1[0]), type(lst1[1]))

for i in lst1:
    if(type(i)==int):
        if i > 6:
            print(i)
```

Comment: I did not downvote this answer, but I doubt that this is a suitable answer to the question as the question goes more towards implementation details of the Python languange, not towards "how to get rid of my error" (especially as no desired behavior/output is given in the question).

Comment: Not only that (and I'm also not a downvoter) but this isn't the idiomatic way to check the type of values either. You should use `isinstance()`

Comment: @roganjosh it's still one way of doing it isn't it

Comment: @albert oops i only read one part of the question

Comment: The wrong way of doing it, yeah

Comment: Absolutely not. `type()` returns the type of your variable, while `isinstance()`returns a boolean value.

Comment: Well now your answer is ludicrously wrong. `'ac' > 'bc'` is perfectly valid in Python due to lexicographical ordering. I am well aware of what the comparison methods return. "because you can't really compare the characters they're made of. You may compare a string's length, but not the content in itself." is nonsense